# app not running after enabling gcUnmanagedToManaged MDA

Tags: windbg, heap-corruption

Because of heap corruption I enabled gcUnmanagedToManaged MDA through a system environment variable. Unfortunately I can't run my app anymore. I always get something like the following:

```
(a78.1150): Unknown exception - code e053534f (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00dff8ac ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000003 edi=00000000
eip=7779013d esp=00dff85c ebp=00dff8f8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15:
7779013d 83c404          add     esp,4
```

All my threads seem to be killed (XXXX):

```
0:002> !threads
ThreadCount: 5
UnstartedThread: 1
BackgroundThread: 3
PendingThread: 0
DeadThread: 0
Hosted Runtime: no
                                      PreEmptive   GC Alloc           Lock
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State     GC       Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
XXXX    1  c98 00401568      6020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 003c7698     4 STA
XXXX    2  4cc 0040be80      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 003c7698     0 MTA (Finalizer)
XXXX    3 1150 05525948      7220 Disabled 00000000:00000000 003c7698     0 STA System.StackOverflowException (0265106c)
XXXX    4  e2c 055778c0   200b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 003c7698     1 MTA
XXXX    5    0 055b4a28      1600 Enabled  00000000:00000000 003c7698     0 Ukn
```

As soon as I get rid of `COMPLUS_MDA=gcUnmanagedToManaged` it's working as expected. My system is x86 with .net 3.5 SP1.

Any hints?

UPDATE:
I also tried to debug it:

```
0:002> k 0xffff
ChildEBP RetAddr  
00eef8cc 757015e9 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x15
00eef968 75091a2c KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x100
00eef9b0 75094220 KERNEL32!WaitForMultipleObjectsExImplementation+0xe0
00eef9cc 724a7821 KERNEL32!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
00eefa2c 724a777e mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::MainLoop+0xe9
00eefa5c 724a76a5 mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProc+0xe5
00eefa8c 750933aa mscorwks!DebuggerRCThread::ThreadProcStatic+0x9c
00eefa98 777a9ef2 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
00eefad8 777a9ec5 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
00eefaf0 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it? `e053534f` is stack overflow, and you will likely get extremely long call stack, so you will have to print it with something like `k <n>`, where <n> is large number like 10000. Close to the very bottom of the stack you will find relevant frames.

Comment: @Seva: Thank you for commenting. Yes, but I don't see anything useful (see my updated post).

Comment: You will need to run ~X kb 0xffff where X is the thread ID that had the stack overflow. It looks like the thread you got was the injected debug thread. Note the command I used is pulled from memory and it might not be correct, but it should put you on the right path

Comment: @Zipper: I'm not able to switch to any other thread. I always get "Illegal thread error in '~Xs'". I think it's because all threads are already killed (XXXX)...